# Transaction synchronisation: how to create ChainedKafkaTransactionManager bean with Reactor Kafka and R2DBC

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, r2dbc, reactive-kafka, reactor-kafka

I have a following consumer in my Spring Boot (WebFlux/R2DBC/Reactor Kafka) application

```kotlin
    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent::class)
    fun onMyEvent() {
        kafkaReceiver
            .receive()
            .doOnNext { record ->
                val myEvent = record.value()
                myService.deleteSomethingFromDbById(myEvent.myId)
                .thenEmpty {
                    record.receiverOffset().acknowledge()
                }.subscribe()
            }
            .subscribe()
    }
```

I would like to add transaction synchronisation for Kafka and DB transactions. After reading docs and some stakoverflow questions

- [Transaction Synchronization in spring boot with Database+ kafka example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170932/transaction-synchronization-in-spring-boot-with-database-kafka-example)
- [Spring Kafka ChainedKafkaTransactionManager doesn't synchronize with JPA Spring-data transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804826/spring-kafka-chainedkafkatransactionmanager-doesnt-synchronize-with-jpa-spring)
- [Transaction Synchronization in Spring Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354521/transaction-synchronization-in-spring-kafka)
- [Spring @Transactional with a transaction across multiple data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954763/spring-transactional-with-a-transaction-across-multiple-data-sources)

seems like `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` would be the way to go.

But following code won't work as ChainedKafkaTransactionManager expects transaction managers of type `PlatformTransactionManager`. So parameter `r2dbcTransactionManager` is not accepted.

```kotlin
    @Bean(name = ["chainedTransactionManager"])
    fun chainedTransactionManager(
        r2dbcTransactionManager: R2dbcTransactionManager,
        kafkaTransactionManager: KafkaTransactionManager<*, *>
    ) = ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager, r2dbcTransactionManager)
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in chaining transactions for Kafka consumers. Only for publishers, i.e. outgoing messages.

But you should make sure not to process the same message more than once.

```kotlin
@EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent::class)
fun onMyEvent() {
  kafkaReceiver.receive()
    // Make sure to have unique index on (topic, partition, offset)
    // so you receive a ConstraintViolationException
    .flatMap { r ->
      val msg = ConsumedMessage(r.topic(), r.partition(), r.offset())
      consumedMessagesRepository.save(msg).thenReturn(r)
    }
    .onErrorContinue {ex, r -> log.warn("Duplicate msg") }
    .flatMap { r ->
      myService.deleteSomethingFromDbById(r.value().myId)
        .thenReturn(r)
    }
    .flatMap { r ->
      r.receiverOffset().commit()
    }
    .subscribe()
}
```